# apache flink's union type confusion?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I try to union a number of flink DataSets. They are contained in a Seq. The following is code that produces the problem

```
case class clickZap ( date: LocalDateTime, stbId:String, channelId :Int , nozap:Boolean)
val afterLastz: DataSet[clickZap]= ... 

val ma_range: IndexedSeq[DataSet[(Int, Option[(java.time.LocalDateTime, String, Int, Boolean)])]]  = for (i  <- Range (0,min_n))
      yield afterLastz.reduceGroup(it =>(i, maxBeforezTCZ(it,at plusMinutes(i))))
//val ma_all =  ma_range.slice(1, min_n).foldLeft(ma_range.head)(_ union _)
val ma_all = ma_range.head union(ma_range.tail.head)
```

What I get is a

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: Cannot union
>   inputs of different types. Input1=scala.Tuple2(_1: Integer, _2:
>   Option[scala.Tuple4(_1: GenericType [java.time.LocalDateTime], _2:
>   String, _3: Integer, _4: Boolean)]), input2=scala.Tuple2(_1: Integer,
>   _2: Option[scala.Tuple4(_1: GenericType[java.time.LocalDateTime], _2: String, _3: Integer, _4: Boolean)])

What am I missing? The types are not different, are they? The union operator is supposed to be cheap, so it seems unattractive to circumvent the problem.
I provided the first two lines of code as an argument that the types of the data in the DataSets are the same.
I used flink versions 0.9.0 and 0.9.1

Comment: GenericType must not necessarily be equal. What data type is it actually?

Comment: Do you really want to perform an all reduce operation for each element in `Range(0, min_n)`? Wouldn't it be better to do create for every element in `afterLastz` all the possible values for the different time differences, then group by the time difference and then calculate `maxBeforezTCZ` in each group? That way you would also avoid the `union`. Anyway, knowing the type of `afterLastz` would be helpful.

Comment: Mathias the data type parameter is a  java.time.LocalDateTime.

Comment: Till the type of afterLastz is DataSet[clickZap]. clickZap is a case class. I added an annotation to the code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a bug in Flink's own typing system. The `OptionTypeInfo`, which represents a Scala `Option`, did not define a proper `equals` method. Consequently, the two `OptionTypeInfos` weren't detected to be equal.

I created a [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-2633) and opened a [Pull Request](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/1104) to fix the problem. The pull request should be merged in two days. If you then use the latest `0.10-SNAPSHOT` version, then your problem should be fixed.

Comment: That sheds light on the issue. The lack of an equals() method is [reflected in the documentation.](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.9/api/scala/index.html?org/apache/flink/api/scala/operators/IterativeDataSet.html#org.apache.flink.api.scala.typeutils.OptionTypeInfo)  My guess is that there is the same problem with Either/EitherTypeInfo.

Comment: @SpyrosKomninos, you're completely right. Thanks for catching it :-) I'll also address this bug.